# Handle key events without focus

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I wonder is there a way, to handle key event if my application not in focus.

For example, I create a small app. It has a transaparent background. When I run my app via Xcode(run option), it is in focus and handle key events. But if I click anywhere, focus lost and key events doesn't handled. All I need is handle key event even if my application not in focus(with transaparent background), and if send key events to other windows(in focus), if this key events won't needed for my application. Dropl is application, that doing just what I want. But I don't have the source.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solwed my problem using DDHotKeyExample from https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey